# OpenSSL Timestamp log location

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, openssl, perl

I am trying to debug an openssl ts based perl http server. The server logs display an openssl ts -reply command failing with exit code 1.

Where can I see the logs related to this openssl command, or a more verbose explanation of the error? The OS is RHEL 7.3

Comment: If any logs are kept at all and where they are kept is fully in control of the specific application which uses `openssl ts`. The question thus cannot be answered based on the provided information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the and I ended up spending a few days exploring the http server's calling perl script, and figured out a way to enforce it to display not only the error code but the stderr as well:

140201521313600:error:2F083075:time stamp routines:**TS_RESP_CTX_set_signer_cert:invalid signer certificate purpose**:crypto/ts/ts_rsp_sign.c:159:

So I ended up creating a new cert according to the following requirements:

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3161.txt (Section 2.3 is the related part)